# How to replace a $ sign in flutter / dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to do something with this XML:

https://www.projectaon.org/data/trunk/en/xml/01fftd.xml

I can load it and convert it to JSON OK. I'm trying to read the name of the book - it is in my JSON object in the key $t (it comes like this and I can't change it). Every time I try and use the dollar sign in my key like this

```
 jsondata['gamebook']['meta']['title']['$t'] // $t causes errors
```

The $t causes a problem. How can I access this part of the JSON? Or how can I replace the $t in response I get when loading it before I convert it to JSON? Every time I try and replace "$t" with replaceAll I get errors. I guess caused by flutter's/dart's string interpolation?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the dollar sign ? By using `\$` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dollar($)` has a special significance in `Dart` for [string interpolation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings). You can use `['\$t']` instead of `['$t']` in order to hint that this Dollar sign is not a special char.